# USB mouse jiggler and logs

Tags: usb, logging

A lot of companies have software that detects usb mouse jigglers, heard it can get you fired. Even without downloading software, are jigglers creating USB logs and will it give employers all my details about what I have hooked up to my computer?

Comment: Pro-tip - if you're worried about what your employer thinks about the things you're hooking up to your company-owned computer then don't hook it up.  Assume that your employer knows everything about what is going on with your computer.

Comment: Yes. My employer monitors all USB devices plugged in (we work with PII and banking data)

Comment: For those who are wondering what a mouse jiggler is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_jiggler

Comment: About the only way to get around this would be an external mechanical device to jiggle the mouse currently attached in the approved manner. An Arduino driving a servo would do the trick. As others have recommended, if your employer considers this a termination offense, it will not remove that risk.

Comment: _"Even without downloading software […]"_ - what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the details of what monitoring software your employer uses, and which jiggler you plan to use, the question cannot be directly answered.

Your best guide is the precautionary principle, assume that if you try to do something to deceive your employer, it could be detected.

Depending on the nature of your work, some people might find it morally reprehensible that your employer would track your activity on their computer, and use this information towards assessing your job performance.

So you can consider a few actions:

- full compliance with your employer's rules
- attempt to deceive using things like jigglers, and risk penalty or job termination, and not getting a good reference later
- open and honest conversation with your employer about ways to measure your job performance that don't resort to these metrics
- proactively try to find a new job with an employer who cares more about you and your output, rather than time-based metrics on your computer